# Attributes sent from link_to to create action is not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following link_to in my index.html.erb. Whenever I click on the link, it will create a new record in retrieval_requests table but for some reason user_id and package_id was not saved.

I'm not sure on how to go about this. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

index.html.erb

```
.
.
<%= link_to "Retrieve this package", retrieval_requests_path(user_id: current_user.id, package_id: item.package.id), :method => :post %>
.
.
```

retrieval_requests_controller.rb

```
class RetrievalRequestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @items = Item.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

  def create
    @retrieval_request = RetrievalRequest.new(params[:retrieval_request])
    if @retrieval_request.save
      redirect_to retrieval_requests_path, notice: "Successfully created retrieval request."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a link and not a form, you're going to have to create the record with the individual params.

So instead of using `params[:retrieval_request]` (which don't exist), use `params[:user_id]` and `params[:package_id]`.

When you pass parameters to a link helper, such as:

```
retrieval_requests_path(user_id: 3, package_id: 26)
```

It will create a URL that looks something like the following, depending on how you set up your routes:

```
"/retrieval_requests/3/26"
# or with no user_id or package_id set in routes:
"/retrieval_requests?user_id=3&package_id=26"
```

Then in your controller you need to grab those params separately.

Comment: Thanks. That works... '@retrieval_request = RetrievalRequest.new(:user_id => params[:user_id], :package_id => params[:package_id])'